# How to screen-scrape AS400 with PHP?

Tags: php, screen-scraping, ibm-midrange

Is there a free way to do screen scraping to AS400 with PHP?

I know about the Zend solution but it's not free.

**Edit**
OK, I'll elaborate.

We have many AS400 applications that were written through the years by some programmers.
Now my boss wants to be able to use their screens outside of AS400.
So he told me to do it with c# and ehllapi.
The thing is most of my not very rich programming experience is with PHP and JS and not c#.
I have found about a single guide about screen scraping with c# and not elaborated enough, and it seems like an almost if not completely impossible job for me, unless I do it with the languages I know.

Comment: Please clarify/elaborate what you are seeking, to avoid any potential misunderstanding. Normally when we refer to screen scraping, we mean capturing a 5250 ("green screen") session's datastream, without touching the original [RPG/COBOL] application program(s), and translating this into an HTTP browser based session.  But I want to make sure you no not mean that you have a PHP browser-based application already, and wish to capture the daydream from that.

Comment: Yes, I want to take the data (fields) in screens of existing AS400 programs without touching them and stream it into html pages with the help of PHP.
I only have AS400 programs working, no PHP application.

Comment: Let me know if you find anything. I have been looking for quite a while with no success.

Comment: Don't rule out non-free solutions just because they're non-free. The Zend solution may cost money, but it may be cheaper than writing it yourself, particularly if you don't know anything about the protocols involved. (and don't tell me your employer won't stretch to it -- anyone with an AS400 kicking around is well used to spending chunky bits of cash on their IT solutions)

Comment: I do agree with @SDC. I have run into this before and wasted more time that what it was worth.

Comment: @SDC, that's exactly it.  My boss don't want to pay a single dime since we already have licenses for visual studio. Please see my edit at the top as for why my question is about PHP and not visual studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you truly need screen scraping or could you just use PHP (PDO) to use SQL statements to view data kept on the AS/400?

One of my early AS/400 clients thought they wanted to use screen scraping to web-enable some of their applications. They quickly changed their mind though when I showed them how much richer their interface could be using a web browser rather than a green screen.  They ended up discarding the idea of screen scraping and hired some web developers who created PHP pages to manipulate data on the AS/400.

Obviously there are times when simple (or even complex) SQL statements can't do what you need - you can still call programs on the AS/400 from PHP. Take a look at the [PHP Toolkit for i5/OS](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Core-i5/zend-core-i5.htm#i5_php_api_toolkit.htm), available for free from Zend.

Comment: Benny, what will happen when the called program tries to open a display file?

Comment: @Benny Hill, Please see my edit at the top.  I do need screen scraping because we already have dozens (if not hundreds) of written programs. Thanks on the zend tip. But will those functions enable me to do screen scraping? I couldn't find any examples for it. Do you know of any guide for using these function to screen scrape?

Comment: @WarrenT - If I remember correctly you can't call programs with display files. When they decided to start building PHP apps on their intranet (and later their website) they understood they would have to make changes to some existing RPG programs (or write new ones) but they decided that was a better solution for them. In their case I definitely agreed.

Comment: @user7424 The PHP Toolkit will NOT do screen scraping, it simply allows you to write PHP applications in the place of RPG (or COBOL or whatever) programs. The client I spoke of had thousands of programs - it sounds like they were a bigger shop than you, perhaps it was easier for them to simply write new PHP programs rather than do screen scraping. If you truly have to do screen scraping and it's just you working on this project I think your best bet is going to be to buy a prepackaged solution. If that's not an option, I'd go with Buck's suggestion.

Comment: By the way, when we installed the Zend Server stuff there was a web-based 5250 emulator - essentially a green screen running inside the browser. I seem to remember thinking it was quite slow but that was many years ago, I would expect them to have made things better by now. It's worth checking out, especially if it will keep you from having to learn the 5250 protocol and coding a bunch of stuff from scratch. I'm also unsure of any costs associated with that - we only fired up the one session a couple of times for the "Oh, isn't that cool!" factor.

Comment: @BennyHill - I did not think PHP session could handle the 5250 display file.  As you know, many companies have a tremendous investment in these green-screen applications, which can often include complex business logic.  Replacing this logic wholesale, can be an expensive proposition, and perhaps entail risk of not replicating some critical part of that logic.

Comment: @WarrenT - obviously every business must evaluate for themselves which solutions make the most sense for them. If your green screen apps are written in such a way that the business logic can be moved into it's own self-contained program for instance, then you can use either a green-screen front-end or a web-based front end to interact with the business logic. That's not always possible - but we know making things "modular" is the best way to do things.

Comment: @BennyHill - how does it make more sense to rewrite thousands of programs istead of just one that does screen scraping? the first option can take years if not dozens of years while the second one, I hope, only a few weeks.

Comment: @user7424 - they didn't rewrite thousands of programs. They selected the ones that were most relevant and made whatever small changes they had to in order to make them more modular so they could be used with web-based and/or green-screen front ends. As for a developer creating a screen scraping application that will work with all existing green-screen programs, especially if s/he has no previous knowledge of the 5250 protocol, in "only a few weeks"... that is highly unlikely. Writing something like that from scratch is a considerable undertaking.

Comment: @BennyHill - it seems [this guy](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9615/Using-EHLLAPI-in-C) did it faily easy. Sure, it's c# and not PHP, but still... Am I missing something?

Comment: @user7424 - A couple of things that come to mind that *might* cause you problems with the C#/DLL approach: differing versions of Client Access (no guarantee that the DLL methods are the same) and it's not a cross-platform solution. Keep in mind with this solution you'd have to create a new C# screen for every green screen you want to scrape, dealing with 80/132 column changes, etc. If you choose to go this route and you need cross-platform functionality you might want to look at the tn5250 project Buck Calabro mentioned and also look at wxWidgets rather than C#.

Answer (score 2):

Write a proxy server that sits between your midrange machine and the TN5250 client.  It's regular TCP/IP sockets.  You'll need to understand how [TN5250](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1205.html) works.

Comment: Is there an elaborated guide on how to do that?

Comment: Have a look at PHProxy.  The [tn5250 project](http://tn5250.sourceforge.net/) at sourceforge might be helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

Consider tweaking your RPG applications into RPG/OA applications, rather than screen-scraping per se.  This is *much* simpler than replacing everything with PHP. Most RPG/OA solutions do come with a price tag, and you did ask for a free solution.  So check out [OpenRPGUI](http://OpenRPGUI.com), an open source solution.  Read about it [here](http://www.iprodeveloper.com/article/application-modernization/you-can-handle-rpg-oa-65986).